# Product of directed partial orders

Tags: order-theory, products

Is a product poset (with componentwise order) of nonempty posets a [dcpo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_partial_order) if and only if each multiplier is a dcpo? (for both binary and arbitrary products)

Comment: In one direction it is easy: Suppose one multiplier is not a dcpo. Take a chain with fixed elements (thanks our posets are nonempty) from other multipliers and for this multiplier take the values which form a chain without the join. This proves that the product is not a dcpo.

Comment: I've also asked it at sci.math: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/leERWkEI91I